# How to create s3 bucket with logging enabled and make it private using boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, bucket

I want to create a bucket with

1. Logging
2. Encryption
3. Private, and
4. Alert

when accessed without https. How can I achieve this?

I have tried few lines using boto3 but getting error in logging?

```
def create_S3_Bucket(env, filepath):
s3_client= AWSresourceconnect(filepath,'s3')
bucket_name ="s3bucket123"
print(bucket_name)
try:
    s3_bucket= s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
    print('bucket created')
    print(s3_bucket)
    response = s3_client.put_bucket_encryption(Bucket=bucket_name,
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration={
            'Rules': [
                {
                    'ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault': {
                        'SSEAlgorithm': 'AES256'

                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    )
    print("response of encrytpion")
    print(response) #prints metadata successfully

    responselogging = s3_client.put_bucket_logging(
        Bucket= bucket_name,
        BucketLoggingStatus={
            'LoggingEnabled': {
                'TargetBucket':bucket_name,
                'TargetGrants': [
                    {
                        'Grantee': {
                            'Type': 'Group',
                            'URI': 'http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers',
                        },
                        'Permission': 'READ',
                    },
                ],
                'TargetPrefix': 'test/',
            },
        },
    )

    print("response of logging")
    print(responselogging) 

    Output= bucket_name
except Exception as e:
    Output = "error:" + str(e)
    print(e)  #error as An error occurred (InvalidTargetBucketForLogging) when calling the PutBucketLogging operation: You must give the log-delivery group WRITE and READ_ACP permissions to the target bucket
    bucket_name = ''
retrun Output
```

I want to enable

1. Logging
2. Private bucket and objects
3. Encryption

Comment: "getting error in logging?" - which error?

Comment: @Marcin, the error is 
error as An error occurred (InvalidTargetBucketForLogging) when calling the PutBucketLogging operation: You must give the log-delivery group WRITE and READ_ACP permissions to the target bucket